# Android SDK - Java - listview.setAdapter fails

Tags: java, android, listview, sdk

I have the below sourcecode running perfectly.
It doesn't do much, but it runs i can point, click and fiddle around.

As soon as i uncomment:

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

All hell brakes loose and i can't really se why.

```
05-22 18:12:52.962: E/AndroidRuntime(27603): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 18:12:52.962: E/AndroidRuntime(27603): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080001 type #0x12 is not valid
```

I have no bloody clue what this highlevel language is spitting in my face..
Java, i hate you.. but we're stuck with each other so if anyone could help me, that would be swell.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theList);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
            "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
            "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }

        final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.id.theList, list);
        //listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.d("Test", item);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void listFiles() {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "");
        File files[] = file.listFiles();
        for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            String filename = files[i].getName();
            Integer pos = filename.indexOf(".pdf");
            if (pos >= 0) {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + filename);
                //listItems.add(filename);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
          for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
          }
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
          String item = getItem(position);
          return mIdMap.get(item);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
          return true;
        }

    }
}
```

What i'm trying to do, is just to add items to my listobject called `@+id/theList`.
It appears harder than anything i've ever done.. the list isn't visible in my application for some reason even tho it appears to be pupulated with items (ran a .log function in the adding loop and the row after is a .add that doesn't give an exception)

Comment: try with : StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

Comment: Looks good, and it's not just android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 R.layout.simple_list_item_1. This is the id of basic items for android listView. And happy :)

Comment: @Torexd, It makes perfect sense when you realize what is going on. In the Adapter you are telling it what data to use with your array. That second parameter, however, is not supposed to be the ListView the data is going in. The ListView is the view (think MVC). The adapter is the model. Now this is where it gets a little freaky in Android. The model (adapter) is the one that knows what the view for each list item and handles it. The second id is the layout that is supposed to be used for the view for each list item. The adapter gets the layout for each list item. You associate the adapter with

Comment: the list. Each item in the list gets populated by calling getView in the adapter. I have a private app that I use to keep track of the books in my library. So I have a custom adapter that uses a view that displays the books cover, title, author, and publisher. Sorry about the massive comment, but I hope this helps you and any future readers who find themselves in the same situation.

Comment: Yepp i'm beginning to grasp the concept :) As mentioned in the comments below last time i picked up Java was 8 years ago at a minimum, back then Android wasn't even around. So this was a real eye-opener for me to say the least :) Python, C/C++ is a hell of a lot more cleaner than Java operations (for one who's not used to the way of Java) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's look at what you are doing here:

`final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.id.theList, list);
        //listview.setAdapter(adapter);`

You don't override any of the array adapter constructors, so you're calling this array adapter constructor:

`public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

So, what are the arguments you are passing in?

- context is your activity (this) which is fine
- textViewResourceId is your list id.
- objects is your list

The problem is the second argument `textViewResourceId`. This is a bit misleading in this context since it is not asking for the resource id of the your actual list. It's looking for a resource id of how the row items are laid out.

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` is a default layout of items in a listview.

You could define your own layout, for example,if you wanted to have an icon or more text or whatever.

But this is why `setAdapter` is throwing an exception.

Comment: as always, great explanations from you @cbrulak :)

Comment: Thanks Torxed! Glad I could help. Feel free to reach out if you need help with other things :)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt you be using this constructor?

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)
```

so you could do

```
new StableArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.r.id.text1,list);
```

you really dont even need that custom class if all you are doing is just displaying text in a row and you can just use `SimpleAdapter`

Comment: Have never developed for android, and it was 5 years since i last picked up Java.. so i'm not sure if what you're saying is correct or adds to anything, sorry :/

Answer (score 0):

To use the default implementation of ArrayAdapter, the view passed in the constructor (textViewResourceId) should be a layout element that contains an text view element named "text1".

As @tyczj suggested, if your are wanting a simple basic list, you can use "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1". If you look in the source code it is a layout element that has only one child element. A text view named "text1".

Comment: Thank you for clearing that out and making the info a little more constructive. Having some trouble finding R in the android chain but i for once get the idea at least of what i'm looking at. Havn't done any Java in ~8 years and back then, android didn't excist so..